# Regular expression for java.util.regex.Pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a suitable regular expression to use java.util.regex.Pattern

I am using the regular expression shown below to match Strings like so: `feed_user_at_gmail_dot_com_testfile`

```
final static Pattern PATTERN1 = Pattern.compile("feed_(.*)_([^_]*)");
```

This works as expected. But, I need to create another Pattern to match Strings like so: `feed_user_at_gmail_dot_com_testfile_ts_20120413_dot_175531_dot_463`

The difference is that the second String is a time stamped version of the first String. These two Strings are examples of file names in my database and I need to identify them both separately. The time stamped version is appended with `_ts_` followed by DATE as shown above. All dots in the DATE are changed to `_dot_`

Thanks,
Sony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
"feed_(.*)_([^_]*)_ts_[1-9]+(_dot_[1-9]+)*"
```

Or better yet,

```
"feed_(.*)_([^_]*)_ts_[1-9]+(_dot_[1-9]+){2}"
```

if dates always have exactly two dots.